# C++ exe writes different text output to a file when called from cygwin

Tags: c++, encoding, cygwin, ofstream

I need help on this it appears to me a mysterious problem, where I cannot see how to solve it.

I have written a C++ exe. It has the very simple task of reading small text files containing some lines like:

```
house <CLASSMISSING> missing    
roof <CLASSMAJORWEAR> major wear
```

do some comparison on the TAGS and write very simple results (text) to a .csv file.
An output would look like:

```
house 11; MISSING
```

this output is produced by:

```
fout << argv[3] << ";" << sC_damages.get_damage(sC_damages.worst_dam_ID).c_str() << "\n";
```

where argv[3] is an identifier string in this case "house 11" passed to the program on the command line and the sC_damages.get_damage outputs a string in this case "MISSING".
The result is written to a file opened in append mode in the following way:

```
ofstream fout(argv[2], ios::app);
```

When I run this from a CMD (Win7) or out of Visual Studio 2010 everything is fine. Yet I need to / want to run it from a bash script under cygwin.

When I call the C++ program several times from a cygwin32 bash command line with:

```
cygdrive/d/CCpp/program.exe "out_tmp//house11.txt" houses.csv "house 11"
```

and then look at the results in the output file houses.csv (for each identical command line call the identical result should be appended) I get the following calamity:

```
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;™
ï2åK¨vhouse 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11òëc‰çÁu*Ihouse 11;MISSING
```

So every now and then mysterious characters are inserted.There is no pattern for it.
The same output when called from a CMD looks perfect:

```
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
house 11;MISSING
```

I really cannot understand how ofstream (which I use in the C++ program to write to the file houses.csv) produces different output when the program is called from a CMD or from cygwin bash.

Please help!

P.S.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "damageClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    char ch;
    int dam_ID = 0;
    int dam_ID_tmp = 0;
    char sc_damage[80];
    char dump[256];
    string uT_Tag;
    string source = argv[3];


    damages sC_damages;
    sC_damages.reset();

    //check correct number command line arguments
    if ( argc != 4 )
    {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "<input concord.txt filename> <output csvfilename> <reportfilename> " << endl;
        return(1);
    }


    //input concord.txt file
    ifstream fin(argv[1]);

    //outputcsv file
    ofstream fout(argv[2], ios::app);
    if ( !fout )
    {
        cout << "Unable to open " << argv[2] << " in append mode.\n";
        return (1);
    }

    while ( !fin.eof() )
    {
        while ( fin.get(ch) )
        {

            uT_Tag = "";
            if ( ch == '<' ) //if line in concord.txt starts with <
                fin.putback( '<' );

            //read out damage tag from in between <>
            if (fin.peek() == '<')
            {
                fin.ignore(1, '<');
                fin.getline(sc_damage, 80, '>');
                fin.getline(dump, 256);
                uT_Tag = sc_damage;
                int weight = sC_damages.get_dam_weight(uT_Tag); // weight= only for debug output. Class call necessary to compute worst_dam_ID
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "writing: " << argv[3] << "; " << sC_damages.get_damage(sC_damages.worst_dam_ID) << endl;
    fout << argv[3] << ";" << sC_damages.get_damage(sC_damages.worst_dam_ID).c_str() << "\n";

    fout.close();
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the definition of the classes:

```
#include "damageClass.h"

//const char *damageTags[5] = { "CLASSOK", "CLASSMINORWEAR", "CLASSMAJORWEAR", "CLASSBROKEN", "CLASSMISSING"};
//const char *damages[5] = { "NODAMAGE", "MINORWEAR", "MAJORWEAR", "BROKEN", "MISSING"};

damages::damages()
{
    this->damageClasses.clear();

    damageClass dC;
    dC.m_damageTag = "";
    dC.m_damage = "NOFINDING";
    dC.dam_weight = 0;
    this->damageClasses.push_back(dC);

    dC.m_damageTag = "CLASSOK";
    dC.m_damage = "NODAMAGE";
    dC.dam_weight = 1;
    this->damageClasses.push_back(dC);

    dC.m_damageTag = "CLASSMINORWEAR";
    dC.m_damage = "MINORWEAR";
    dC.dam_weight = 2;
    this->damageClasses.push_back(dC);

    dC.m_damageTag = "CLASSMAJORWEAR";
    dC.m_damage = "MAJORWEAR";
    dC.dam_weight = 3;
    this->damageClasses.push_back(dC);

    dC.m_damageTag = "CLASSBROKEN";
    dC.m_damage = "BROKEN";
    dC.dam_weight = 4;
    this->damageClasses.push_back(dC);

    dC.m_damageTag = "CLASSMISSING";
    dC.m_damage = "MISSING";
    dC.dam_weight = 5;
    this->damageClasses.push_back(dC);
}

damages::~damages()
{
    this->damageClasses.clear();
}

int damages::get_dam_weight(string UT_damageTag)
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < this->damageClasses.size(); i++ )
    {
        damageClass dC = this->damageClasses.at(i);
        if (dC.m_damageTag == UT_damageTag)
        {
            this->worst_dam_ID = max(dC.dam_weight, this->worst_dam_ID);
            return dC.dam_weight;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

string damages::get_damage(int dam_weight)
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < this->damageClasses.size(); i++ )
    {
        damageClass dC = this->damageClasses.at(i);
        if (dC.dam_weight == dam_weight)
        {
            return dC.m_damage;
        }
    }
    return "ERROR: no matching damage class";
}

void damages::reset()
{
    this->worst_dam_ID = 0;
}
```

and this the declaration of the classes:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


//class description
class damageClass 
{
public:
    //attributes
    string m_damageTag;
    string m_damage;
    int dam_weight;
};


class damages
{
public:
    damages(void);
    ~damages(void);

    //attributes
    vector<damageClass> damageClasses;
    int worst_dam_ID;

    //methods
    int get_dam_weight(string UT_damageTag);
    string get_damage(int dam_weight);
    void reset();
};
```

Comment: seems like undefined behavior. we can tell **nothing** unless you show us some actual code.

Comment: So it looks like argv[3] is losing the terminating null.  So somewhere, the code is corrupting memory.  You probably need to step through with a debugger and watch the result of argv[3] at each line and see when it changes.  Using std::string was a good idea, since fixed length char arrays are troublesome.  I might start by changing sc_damange and dump to strings, and use std::getline instead of fin.getline since that is safer.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try your advice. What I already did is just leave out argv[3] for output. I even just defined a string inside like "xxxxxxx" and made this the only output. So no other output than a string defined within the program and still I got this effect (I already can't believe this anymore, although I think I did it correctly). After trying a lot the only thing left over appeared to be, that a call from cygwin leads to different behaviour than a call from cmd.

Comment: I also thought argv[3] was losing the terminating null. But (less often) also sC_damages.get_damage(sC_damages.worst_dam_ID).c_str() appears to be losing the terminating null. But how should it sometimes lose it and sometimes don't?

Comment: I also stepped through with debugger. Yet the problem is, this effect does not occur from within VS. And I cannot debug with a call from cygwin.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question but do you use multibyte/unicode? I've heard cygwin had some problems with adding the null termination to non ascii encoding

Comment: Hm the thing is I do not understand why and how cygwin is involved in writing the strings. I start the C++ exe from cygwin. But the C++ exe is then writing strings to a file. Why and how is this writing to a file by the C++ exe influenced through cygwin?

Comment: Does e.g. a C++ exe get different environment parameters when started from cygwin than when started from cmd? Is there e.g. a mechnism telling the C++ exe to use such and such encoding when writing to a file?

Comment: Following the idea that something with the null termination sucks I just forced a null termination. "sc_damage[strlen(sc_damage) - 2] = '\0';" truncating the strings (after having strcpy them into char[] variables) I still get "house žIþQW®;òRùhouse ;MISSI" this time after the 15th call :-(

Answer (score 0):

Right, this was a difficult one. I am using SafeGuard LanCrypt. Apparently when appending files under Cygwin random signs are produced.
Writing to an unencrypted share solves the problem.